# Delete Excel Sheets With Name Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, criteria

The Correct Code is

```
        Private Sub DeleteTSheets()
        Dim xl As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Patches\Main_Final.xlsm")
        For Each ws in wb.sheets
           If InStr(1, ws.Name, "T") Then
              If len(ws.name)=3 then
                   ws.delete()
              End If
           End If
        Next
       wb.Close(Savechanges:=vbTrue)
       End Sub
```

The Code is running only when I removed all macros from the excel sheet!!!

Thanks, Regards
Moheb Labib

Comment: You ask so many questions (more than 1), the answer to "The code does not work or give an error" is: Please inform us what error you are getting then, maybe, someone can be of help.

Comment: Please remove the `On Error` lines, you might actually see what error you get.

Comment: To be clear, best practices support use of `On Error` with redirect to an error handle section. Rarely though is `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo 0` ever useful which suppress useful error messages.

Comment: @Luuk , Thanks your support, However sometimes you do not have certain error to output maybe because of the logic may be not arranged, like this case because the code is correct but it does not act.

Comment: @Meho2016: In your question i do read "The code does not work",  and now you claim the code is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, for integer loops use `For` and not `Do` loop and handle code logic without `On Error` redirects. Additionally, since your second code implementation works, your main issue is conflating VBA and VB.Net. Though they share same constructs, these two are fundamentally different languages. VBA is an extended utility with MS Office applications while VB.Net is a standalone general purpose language with its .NET sibling, C#.

Consequently, you cannot exactly copy/paste code between the two types. Main difference with VBA and VB.Net is initializing the COM object, `Excel.Application`. VB.Net (like C#) requires sourcing in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` API.

**VBA**

```vb
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
```

**VB.Net** (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-basic-net))

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
...

Dim xl As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
```

---

**C#** (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects)) *(as comparison)*

```c
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...

var xl = new Excel.Application();
```

---

Additionally, since COM ([Command Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model)) is not limited to Microsoft tools but available resource on Windows machines, other COM-connected languages ike open source tools can connect to Excel. Notice like VB.Net and C#, the respective COM libraries must be imported (PHP doing so as .ini extension).

**Python**

```
import win32com.client as COM

xl = COM.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

**R**

```
libray(RDOMClient)

xl <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
```

**PHP**

```
$xl = new COM("Excel.Application", NULL, CP_UTF8) or Die ("Did not instantiate Access");
```

Comment: Dear All, I would like to thank you for your replies, However I'm using correct references and the code is working as VBA Very well but not working as VB.net, That's why I am asking, it seems that when I ran the code the file became a read only and it won't accept any changes...Thanks

Comment: The Excel File makes Document Recovery and does not allow the code to run...Thanks

Comment: Above info from replies should have been noted  in the initial question. It is important information related to the problem. You are getting a 'read only' because you do and 'Open', and not a 'Close' for a workbook.

Comment: @Luuk, I used `wb.close (savechanges:=vbTrue)` but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

In the first code try replacing the line `If InStr(1, wb.Sheets(i).Name, "T") Then` with

```
If InStr(1, wb.Sheets(i).Name, "T") > 0 Then
```

In the code you developed try replacing the line `If InStr(1, wb.Sheets(i).Name, "T") Then` with

```
If InStr(1, ws.Name, "T") > 0 Then
```

Remember you are looping with `ws` not `i`

Comment: Dear All, I found The Solution, The Code is correct but it is worked only when I removed all macros from the excel sheet so what is this means?? I Edited the Correct Code